# Is there a difference between Web API and MVC HttpConfiguration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

As an example:

If I was to configure CORS (or whatever) for MVC on a project that contains both MVC and Web API using Http Configuration, would I have to do so twice?

While were at this what about Global Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can have Web API and MVC in one project simultaneously. your config includes for both of them.

Comment: Apologies but my English is not very good. Are you saying: "That there is a single config for both" OR "They each have their own configuration"?